# Launch activity from non-activity class

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to launch an ActivityB from an ActivityA via a class.

So I create my non-activity class in an ActivityA, this way:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    myDialog = new MyDialog(this);

}
```

And I launch my second activity in the class constructor as follows :

```
public MyDialog(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent (context, ActivityB.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

The problem is I would like to acess MyDialog from ActivityB. Is this possible?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: you can create a baseactivity.Mydialog crated on the BaseActivity.activityB extends BaseActivity

Comment: It is impossible. Because your dialog use as context ActivityA.

Comment: looks like right solution it should be an answer not a comment

Comment: Can you please tell me why using a BaseActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: 
You could make your class "MyDialog" static and instead in the constructor, create a void that starts the activityB. 
I'm not sure why do you want to start activityB from activityB but this work if they are in the same application:

```
public static class MyDialog {

    public static void StartDialog(Context context){
        System.out.println("STARTING ACTIVITY B");
        Intent i = new Intent (context, ActivityB.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

And in the Activity B use this call:

```
ActivityA.MyDialog.StartDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

Option 2: 
If you don't want to create MyDialog as static, then:

```
public class MyDialog {

    Context context;

    public MyDialog(Context c){
        context = c;
    }

    public void StartDialog(){
        System.out.println("STARTING ACTIVITY B");
        Intent i = new Intent (context, ActivityB.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

And then, in the ActivityB:

```
ActivityA ma = new ActivityA();
MyDialog md = ma.new MyDialog(getApplicationContext());
md.StartDialog();
```